# How can I access a value in an array stored within another array?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am looking for a way to access an array item in an array, which is held by another array. I can't quite figure it out :/

I have 2 scripts: `Game_Manager.cs` and `Board.cs`.

In `Board.cs` I have the following variables. (The array size adjusts automatically on start):

```
public Transform[] Clubs_Bottom = new Transform[0];
public Transform[] Clubs_Top = new Transform[0];
public Transform[] Spades_Left = new Transform[0];
public Transform[] Spades_Right = new Transform[0];
public Transform[] Diamonds_Left = new Transform[0];
public Transform[] Diamonds_Right = new Transform[0];
public Transform[] Hearts_Bottom = new Transform[0];
public Transform[] Hearts_Top = new Transform[0];
```

In `Game_Manager.cs` I have the following method:

```
public void setCardBoardSlot(int Hand_CardNumber)
{
    Array[] ArrayList = new Array[8];       // The card arrays

    // Fill our array list
    ArrayList[0] = Board.Script.Diamonds_Left;
    ArrayList[1] = Board.Script.Diamonds_Right;
    ArrayList[2] = Board.Script.Clubs_Top;
    ArrayList[3] = Board.Script.Clubs_Bottom;
    ArrayList[4] = Board.Script.Spades_Left;
    ArrayList[5] = Board.Script.Spades_Right;
    ArrayList[6] = Board.Script.Hearts_Bottom;
    ArrayList[7] = Board.Script.Hearts_Top;

    // Acces Array item 1's array, and the first item in that array
    ArrayList[0[0]].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer().sprite=SpriteManager.Script.setActive();
}
```

This method is just demonstrative until i find out how to access each array item. I get the following error on the 2nd to last line when I use this code:
`Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'int'`

Comment: `ArrayList[0]` doesnt contains sprites, but the other array, which is why I used [0[0]]. The first `0` to access `ArrayList[0]` and the 2nd `0` to access `Diamonds_Left[0]`

Comment: `ArrayList[0][0]` ?

Comment: @GertKommer: The Array class is essentially generic - so an array of Array can contain further arrays of different types - so an explicit cast is required otherwise you will get a compile error _"Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expession of type 'Array'"_

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearing that up, I was curios as to why that code didn't work either :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Array class essentially contains a generic array - so an array of Array can contain arrays of different types (which may change at runtime). Accesing an element of that array returns a single instance of class Array (not the array itself) so using ArrayList[0][0] would result in a compiler error *"Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Array'"*.

Using an array of class Array you would need to explicitly cast the array element to your array type (which is an array of Transform) & then access the first element in this way :

```
((Transform[])ArrayList[0])[0].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer().sprite=SpriteManager.Script.setActive();
```

As all of your contained arrays are of the same type - a simpler way would be to use an array of array of Transform - your declaration of ArrayList would become :

```
Transform[][] ArrayList = new Transform[8][];
```

the assignments to each array element would be unchanged and then you could simply use:

```
ArrayList[0][0].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer().sprite=SpriteManager.Script.setActive();
```

Note that ArrayList is a defined class type in C# - although the compiler can determine by context that you are referring to the variable, in my opinion, it is better to avoid using .Net class names as variable names.

Comment: Yeah after looking at the Jagged Arrays page [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays), I used:
`
Transform[][] ArrayList = 
         { ... }

To declare my Array. All works fine now :)
Thanks a lot for the help anyway